# Disabling "Documentation" popup while writing xml file on Android-Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio

I'm writing an **xml file in Android-Studio**. I start typing `<LinearLay` and then press **enter** to confirm the suggestion, getting obviously this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width=""
    android:layout_height=""></LinearLayout>
```

Since `width` and `height` are not yet specified it **always** appears a new window (whose header is "*Documentation*") with the following error message:

> The view should be only big enough to enclose its content (plus padding).

Since this is pretty much annoying, **is there a way to disable this behavior?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions:

**1. Unpinning the popup window**

[image: Unpinning documentation popup window]

Now there will be only a small popup that does not have to be closed to continue typing. See this GIF animation:

[image]

---

**2. Disabling "Autopopup Documentation"**

In *Preferences > Editor > General > CodeCompletion* uncheck *Autopopup documentation in (ms)*.

[image]

However, this disables all the autopopup documentations, probably also the ones you might want.